# @property decorator on attribute setter

Tags: python

The following code throws an `AttributeError: can't set attribute` error:

```
# code_1
class Pair(object):        
    def __init__(self):
        self._k1 = 0
        self._k2 = 0
    @property            
    def k1(self, k1):
        self._k1 = k1
    @property
    def k2(self, k2):
        self._k2 = k2    
    @k1.getter
    def k1(self):
        return self._k1
    @k2.getter
    def k2(self):
        return self._k2

>>> p=Pair()
>>> p.k1 = 10
>>> AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

It seems that `p.k1` assignment is causing the error. However, decorating getters with `@property` works perfect. Look at the following code that works fine:

```
# code_2
class Pair(object):        
    def __init__(self):
        self._k1 = 0
        self._k2 = 0
    @property            
    def k1(self):
        return self._k1
    @property
    def k2(self):
        return self._k2
    @k1.setter
    def k1(self, k1):
        self._k1 = k1
    @k2.setter
    def k2(self, k2):
        self._k2 = k2
```

Any idea why `code_1` throws `AttributeError`?

Comment: You don't define a setter for `k1` in the first code snippet, only `@k1.getter`.

Comment: Your second example answers your question.. take a look at it and compare them both

Answer (score 1):

You just need `@property` to get the variable and `setter` to set it.

```
class Pair(object):        
    def __init__(self):
        self._k1 = 0
        self._k2 = 0
    @property             # set the value k1
    def k1(self):
        return self._k1
    @property             # set the value k2
    def k2(self):
        return self._k2
    @k1.setter            # use the setter
    def k1(self, value):
        self._k1 = value
    @k2.setter            # use the setter
    def k2(self, value):
        self._k2 = value
```

Note that the `@getter` are redundant, because `@property` is implicitly a `getter`. Then, you need to define the `@k1.setter` to set the values.

See the [comment below by Lukas Graf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120148/property-decorator-on-attribute-setter/26120296?noredirect=1#comment40937629_26120296) for further good information.

#### Test

```
>>> p=Pair()
>>> p.k1=19
>>> print p.k1
19
```

Comment: See the [documentation on the `@property` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property). `@property` implicitely creates a getter: *"The @property decorator turns the voltage() method into a “getter”..."*

Comment: Many thanks @LukasGraf for the info. I was familiar with `@property` but your comments helped me to fully understand. I hope the solution makes sense now.

Comment: Sort of ;-) The part *"whereas you need to define the @property*" isn't quite right yet, you probably meant to write `@k1.setter`. It's prefixed with `@k1` because the `property` decorator wraps the method `k1` and returns a **property object**. That property object then delegates `__call__` to the original method it wraps, but also provides new decorators that can be accessed with `k1.setter` and `k1.deleter`.

Comment: @LukasGraf thanks again! Updated, linking also to your comment for a better information :)

Comment: You're welcome. There's also some very good information in the description of the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#properties), along with an example Python implementation of the `property()` type.